# RuntimeError: 'cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named numpy.core._methods'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, exe

Have created an executable file for my tkinter GUI, but when trying to run it shows the following error: cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named numpy.core._methods.

My Setup:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os.path

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'include_files':[
            additional_mods,
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
            os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')  
         ],
    },
}
setup(
    name = "converte_planilha",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description= ".py to .exe",
    executables = [Executable("converte_planilha.py")],
    options = options
)
```

When i execute `python setup.py build` this construct the folder build but the executable don't open. When I tried into the CMD I had the follow error:

```
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 27, in <module>
    options = options
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 218, in run
    zipExcludePackages = self.zip_exclude_packages)
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 150, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 475, in _VerifyConfiguration
    sourceFileName)
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: cannot find file/directory named numpy.core._methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']

options = {
   'build_exe': {
       'include_files':[

           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
           os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')  
        ],
        "packages": additional_mods,
   },
}
```